# How can I position intro when materialize tabs is shown (IntroJs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, intro.js

My point is want the tab menu item auto open when it highlighted and if any element within the tab is highlighted the next step will focus on the element.
Anyway, I'm using JSON to provide `steps` I only know that this may use `intro.onbeforechange(function(targetElement) {` but I don't know how to write the condition to make it work

Comment: you need to execute some code when an element is highlighted that switches to the appropriate tab and focus on the element. that's the best answer anyone is going to be able to give you until you post some code.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Ideally a jsfiddle